# Trying to compare migration from Ant build to Maven or Gradle for existing Java Project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, ant

We have a complex Java Project with many processes/applications. Planning to move from Ant build to Maven or Gradle. Trying to compare the migration process to maven  and gradle. Any thoughts and advice? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is your choice. In the future if you want to migrate your app to android, it would be much easier since android studio uses gradle. Also gradle uses groovy, a powerful script language and you can add any java code in your build.gradle.

Disclaimer: This is my personal view, and I am not associated with gradle or maven.

Comment: Yes. this is my personal view.